# Is printf's conversion specifier equivalent to function declaration?

Tags: c, function, printf, type-conversion

Is printf's conversion specifier equivalent to function declaration as far as compiler type checking and automatic conversions go?

I'm trying to understand C basic data types automatic type conversions, promotions etc and wonder if I can use printf instead of dummy function to check what happens.

To make my question clearer with an example,

```
void f1 (int a){}

int main() { f1('c'); return 0; }
```

helps me understand what will happen if I declare a function with an int argument but pass char type in the call.

I want to know if I can just call

```
printf("%i", 'c');
```

for the above purpose.

Also if someone can point to some definitive resources (on web or books) on type representation/conversions/promotion in C, I'll be grateful.

Comment: your example doesn't help much, because in C so called "integer character constants" such as `'c'` are already of type `int`. So wenn passing such a constant to a function that expects an `int` you'll never see a warning, because everything is fine.

Comment: @JensGustedt  That is the purpose of my experiments in the first place - to understand points such as the one mentioned by you. How it works when one type is expected and other is passed- char, int, long. float, string, pointers etc etc. E.g. given here was the most basic of those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

Many compilers don't do any type checking on format strings. gcc does, when `-Wformat` is used, but these checks are separate from those done on assignment.

Parameters to `printf` are passed as they are. The only conversion may be increasing it to a processor word size (this is how `char` becomes `int`) and it doesn't depend on the format string in any way. See Jonathan Leflfer's comment, which explains this more accurately.

Comment: Actually, types `char`, `unsigned char`, `signed char`, `short` and `unsigned short` are all promoted to `int` (or `unsigned int` occasionally — very seldom these days, though), and `float` is promoted to `double`.  This happens with all functions with a variable argument list once you reach the variable part of the argument list (the `...` ellipsis); it also happens when you call a function with no prototype in scope (which you shouldn't do, but which does happen).

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour, I referred to `c` as `char`, but actually I think it's `int`.

Comment: Yes. Character literals like `'c'` are in fact `int` values, in C.

Answer (score 2):

`printf("%i", 'c');` you will get ASCII value of character 'c' which is 99.There are two methods for char to int.

If you just want ASCII value of char simply print `char` using integer specifier.

If you want to convert a `char` to integer(Like '0' to 0 or '1' to 1) then you need to do as follows

```
char a = '4';
int ia = a - '0';  //subtraction of '0'
```

Just an addition for more clarity, specifier in printf says **how much to pop from stack**. If it is `%d` then pop `4 bytes`(assuming int of 4 byte) if it is `%c`, then pop `1 byte` etc.

Comment: Thanks - your last line gives me something to think about.

Comment: ASCII? Why does `'c'` have to correspond to 99? What if EBCDIC is used, instead? Are you aware that a `%c` directive corresponds to an `int` argument?

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour yes i am aware that C always promote types to at least `int`. Here i was talking about printf output which will be `99` which is ASCII value of char `'c'`

Comment: Then I suggest changing the last sentence to state that `%d` corresponds to the same type as `%c`. It's probably a good idea to phrase your first sentence without the word "ASCII", for accuracy: `printf("%d", 'c');` will print the integer value corresponding to the character literal `'c'`.

Answer (score 2):

> Is printf's conversion specifier equivalent to function declaration as
>   far as compiler type checking and automatic conversions go?

No. When you pass a `char` to a variadic function, the value you pass will be promoted to an `int`. This is regardless of the conversion specifier you use. The [C11 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) describes this at §6.5.2.2p7:

> The ellipsis notation in a function prototype declarator causes
>   argument type conversion to stop after the last declared parameter.
>   The default argument promotions are performed on trailing arguments.

Default argument promotions are defined in §6.5.2.2p6 as a superset of integer promotions:

> ... the integer promotions are performed on each argument, and
>   arguments that have type `float` are promoted to `double`. These are
>   called the *default argument promotions*.

... and integer promotions are defined in §6.3.1.1p2:

> If an `int` can represent all values of the original type (as restricted
>   by the width, for a bit-ﬁeld), the value is converted to an `int`;
>   otherwise, it is converted to an `unsigned int`. These are called the
>   *integer promotions*.

---

> To make my question clearer with an example,
>
> void f1 (int a){}
>
> int main() { f1('c'); return 0; }
>
> helps me understand what will happen if I declare a function with an
>   int argument but pass char type in the call.

No, it doesn't. `'c'` is actually an `int`. If you don't believe me, see for yourself:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#ifdef __cplusplus
#error "Don't compile C code with a C++ compiler."
#endif

int main(void) {
    printf("sizeof 'c': %zu\n", sizeof 'c');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer and the point about 'c'. I'll remember to upvote when I have enough points. Thanks for linking the standard as well - going through that is probably what I need right now.

Comment: @Lavya If you haven't already, I suggest reading and doing the exercises within K&R (Kernighan and Ritchie). Once you've done that, H&S (Harbison & Steele) have a reference-style book that might be interesting.

Comment: Yes, going through Ritchie right now. Will try to get my hands on H&S as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you pass **'c'** as an argument to the function **f1** the ASCII value of alphabet **c**  **(99)** will be stored into **a** .So if you modify the **f1** function below

```
void f1 (int a){
 printf("\n %d",a); // prints the ascii value of charecter c
 printf("\n %c",a); //prints the o/p as c
 printf("\n %i",a); //prints the ascii value of charecter c again 
}

O/p for the program

99
c
99
```

You asked

```
I want to know if I can just call printf("%i", 'c');
```

Yes you can then there's no need of the implementation of the function **f1**.

Comment: ASCII? Why does `'c'` have to correspond to 99? What if EBCDIC is used, instead?